# Regex: split a list sentence with 'and' as last splitter (a, b, c and d.)

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of plaintext strings that I need to convert to csv-ish syntax, such that `a, b, c and d.` becomes `"a","b","c","d"`. I'm 90% of the way there with this regex: `/(.+?), /g` (shown as example here: http://regexr.com/3de7o). However I can't get it to also do the same for the 'd' variable; to catch anything after `and` and before `.`.

edit: to clarify, the things needing to be split are usually multiple words, e.g. `This phrase, another phrase and last phrase.` -> `"This phrase","another phrase","last phrase"`

Comment: Per [tag:regex] tag description: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool." And unless you don't have a choice, regex is not the best tool here.

Comment: In my case the applicable tool is regexr.com itself; I was pasting in the sentence lists I wanted to split and I wanted to copy the output from the output field, after the replacement.

Comment: `(?:\sand)?(?:\s)?([^,.]+)`?

Comment: @heemayl that did the trick, yep.

Comment: I hope your data doesn't contain `a, b, a "quoted string" and d`. Also, do you need to deal with the oxford comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
(?:\sand)?(?:\s)?([^,.]+)
```

- `(?:\sand)?` matches zero or one occurrence of a whitespace followed by `and`; this will tackle the last one
- `(?:\s)?` matches zero or one whitespace before the desired pattern
- The above two are put in non-captured group
- in the captured group `([^,.]+)` we get our desired patterns i.e. any characters upto next `,` or `.` (last one).

---

As suggested by @Amadan, as you want to replace, capture the commas as well leaving alone the last `.`:

```
(?:\sand)?(?:\s)?([^,.]+)(?:(,)|.)
```

Now in the replacement, you can use:

```
"$1"$2
```

---

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE7wU7/2)

Comment: `(?:\sand)?(?:\s)?([^,.]+)(?:(,)|.)` -> `"$1"$2` to get rid of the last period.

Comment: Quick question; could it be made to be compatible without a `,` before the `and` as well as with one? Right now `a, b, c, and d.` works but `a, b, c and d.` doesn't; ideally it would work with both. (http://regexr.com/3de7o)

Comment: @IronWaffleMan Try `(?:\sand)?(?:\s)?([^,.\s]+)`

Comment: Nearly, but I get `"a","b","c""d".`, the last comma is missing and the fullstop is there. It also breaks on spaces, so `"this sentence"` would get split into "this""sentence".

Comment: @IronWaffleMan check https://regex101.com/r/hE7wU7/4 .. also then you would need a different replacement pattern.. please add your original input..